# Simplifying a Triple Summation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation, power-series

I have the summation:
$$
\sum_{c=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=c}^n \sum_j \frac{\rho(n,k)}{j!(k-c-j)!(c-j)!}
$$
Where the sum $j$ goes from $0$ to $k-c$ if $k-c \leq c$, but if $k-c \geq c$ then the sum goes from $0$ to $c$. Is there any way to simplify this summation without knowing any properties of $\rho(n,k)$?

UPDATE:
$$
\sum_{c=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=c}^n \sum_j \sum_{l=1}^{n-1} \frac{{n-l \brace c}{l\brace k-c}}{j!(k-c-j)!(c-j)!}
$$
Do you guys think it would be cool to find a value for this summation? For the sake of pure mathematics?

Comment: Are the terms in {} Stirling numbers?

Comment: As for doing this for the sake of pure mathematics, the people here, like poets and improvisers, are in it for the big money.

Comment: @martycohen yes as in stirling numbers

Answer (score 2):

As a start:

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{c=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=c}^n \sum_j \frac{\rho(n,k)}{j!(k-c-j)!(c-j)!}
&= \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{c=1}^{k}\sum_j \frac{\rho(n,k)}{j!(k-c-j)!(c-j)!}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n \rho(n,k) \sum_{c=1}^{k}\sum_j \frac{1}{j!(k-c-j)!(c-j)!}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n \rho(n,k) \sum_{c=1}^{k}\frac1{c!}\sum_j \binom{c}{j}\frac{1}{(k-c-j)!}\\
\end{array}
$

What's next depends on
the range of $j$.

Comment: Updated my question, take a look

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica says that is equivalent to

$$\sum_{c=1}^{n-1} \left(\sum_{k=c}^n \frac{U(-c,-2c+k+1,-1) \rho(n,k) (-1)^{-c}}{c!(k-c)!}\right)$$

where $U$ is [Tricomi's (confluent hypergeometric) function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function). At least that gets rid of one explicit summation with the two cases $k-c \leq c$ and $k-c\geq c$.

Comment: That is very useful actually, but is there nothing more that can be done?

Comment: There could be (I haven't put any thought into it), but why are you interested in a nice-looking representation?

Comment: I may have derived an identity with the sum of stirling numbers that is equal to 2 nontrivial summations of certain summations, it is very cool and im looking to see if it trims down to something beautiful.

Comment: That is a noble pursuit. My answer doesn't make things particularly beautiful; it just re-expresses them in terms of $U$. Good hunting.

Comment: i updated my question, take a look

Comment: I did take a look, but was not able to get anything simpler. Good luck.

Comment: $U(a,b,-1)$ is probably a ratio of factorials, so your sum is a double hypergeometric series